# Inductive Effect (R-NH3+ and R-NH2)

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, inductive-effect

Textbooks I've read state that R-NH3+ has exhibits a greater -I inductive effect than R-NH2 does.

However, I've also read in places that the + charge in R-NH3+ only represents a formal charge and has no physical significance.

If this is the case what explains the greater inductive effect shown by R-NH3+?

Comment: Does a proton have a formal charge without physical significance? As the extra proton is the difference between R-NH2 and R-NH3+.

Comment: I'm actually unsure. I've read in textbooks that compounds like NH4+ and R-NH3+ are formed as a result of coordinate covalent bonds, in which we only represent the + and - "formal" charge to denote exclusively, the donor and acceptor atoms

Comment: All N-H bonds are equivalent there, partial delocalized positive charge distributed on all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your interesting question,
To my knowledge, depending on the solvent you use, you can have a protontaed or a non protonated species. if you are using an aliphatic amine in water, for example, the compound is mostly protonated. For sure the protonated form has a stronger electron-withdrawing effect than its non-protonated form. To answer your question, sure! the charge on the RNH3 group is important and it has a physical significance. It makes the groups more able to attract negative charge through single bond thus increasing the inductive effect on the carbon skeleton of your compound.